# rails - Best practice for creating similar routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, a User can make a Post, and a User can make Correction (think of it as a comment) on another user's post. Each User can have many Posts, and each Post can have many Corrections.

On each show page for a Post, there is a form to create a new Correction. This uses the `user_post_corrections` path.

On the show page for each User, I would like to display each Correction they've submitted for any Post. This requires a `user_corrections` path.

In order to achieve this, I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resources :posts do
      resources :corrections
      end
    end

    resources :users do
      resources :corrections
    end
```

This intuitively feels bad to me, as I've created two nested routes that are very similar to one another.

Is there a better way to do this? My code is working fine as it is but is there a best practice method for implementing this kind of model?

Answer (score 1):

[Routing concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) are an excellent but underused tool for DRYing out your routes:

```
concern :correctable do
  resources :corrections
end

# just an example of multiple concerns
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments
end

resources :users, concerns: :correctable
resources :posts, concerns: [:correctable, :commentable]
```

However you should take when creating nested routes so that you are not nesting needlessly.

Often you might want the collective actions `[new, index, create]` to be scoped by the parent:

```
GET|POST  /posts/:post_id/corrections
GET       /posts/:post_id/corrections/new
```

While you want the member actions to be unscoped since you can always access a record directly if it has a unique id.

```
GET    /corrections/:id
GET    /corrections/:id/edit
PATCH  /corrections/:id
DELETE /corrections/:id
```

To do this you would declare the routes like so:

```
resources :corrections, only: [:show, :update, :edit]

concern :correctable do
  resources :corrections, only: [:new, :index, :create]
end

resources :users, :posts, concerns: [:correctable]
```

The `shallow: true` option does something like this but does not work well when you declare the same `resources` several times as it adds unscoped routes for every call.